# PHP - creating directories with unique names (and concatenating strings!)

Tags: php, directory

I have never used PHP before so apologies for the basic question. I come from a C# background and know that what I'm about to ask is a doddle to do in C#, but just wondered why it wasn't working properly for me in PHP.

So, I have a HTML form and one of the fields has the unique ID of 'author' which contains an author's name. I need to create a folder on the web server with this author name to keep the folders unique. To do this I have done the following:

```
$authorNameText = echo $_POST['author']; //store data in 'author' in a variable   
$authorNameDir = str_replace(" ", "-", authorNameText); //replace spaces in the 'author' field with dashes
$authorNameDir .= "-issue17"; //append 'issue17' to the end of the directory name
```

So say that I typed 'jason brown' into the Author Name field, the folder that would be created would be called 'jason-brown-issue17'.

This folder needs to be inside of a directory called 'user-uploads', so I use an if statement to check if this directory exists.

```
if (!file_exists('\\user-uploads\\'.$authorNameDir)) {
mkdir('\\user-uploads\\'.$authorNameDir, 0777, true);
}
```

I'm attempting to concatenate the variable 'authorNameDir' onto the '\user-uploads\' file path string in order to create the file path. Is this the right way to do this in PHP?

Then to upload the file to the directory (which is an image), I use the following code:

```
$target_dir = '\\user-uploads\\'.$authorNameDir;
```

And the rest of it is W3School's example, see: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Judging by the fact that I either get an HTTP 500 error or I end up with a file called '\user-uploads\jason-brown-issue17\image.png' (for example) in my site's root directory, something's wrong with my syntax! Not 100% sure what, probably something stupid due to my lack of experience with PHP!

What I want is the image to end up in a subfolder called 'jason-brown-issue17' (if 'jason brown' is the contents of the Author field on the HTML form) inside a folder called 'user-uploads' inside the root of the web server.

Any guidance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First I would caution you:  You're doing some very dangerous things, like trying to create a directory where the whole world has full access.

Additionally, best practices are to never write to the file system...  because once you get better at this stuff, you'll start using services like Heroku where you are forced to follow best practices, because you can't use the file system like you want to.

I would recommend saving the image file directly into Amazon S3 (like us pros usually do).  You can grab the Amazon PHP SDK so you don't have to write much code to get this done.  There are plenty of examples on Stackoverflow on how to use AWS S3 to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$authorNameText = echo $_POST['author'];
```

You don't echo here, as you have used an assignment operator `=` just set it as:

```
$authorNameText = $_POST['author'];
```

---

```
$authorNameDir = str_replace(" ", "-", authorNameText);
```

You forgot the `$` on `authorNameText`, so should be:

```
$authorNameDir = str_replace(" ", "-", $authorNameText);
```

---

> This folder needs to be inside of a directory called 'user-uploads',
>   so I use an if statement to check if this directory exists.

I really wouldn't do this in a script, especially not create the directory. Not without considering security implications. Also, if this is the core image directory, you shouldn't need to create or check it in a script, it should already be there as a required structure directory.

---

```
$target_dir = '\\user-uploads\\'.$authorNameDir;
```

Wrong slashes and not sure why so many. Try this instead:

```
$target_dir = 'user-uploads/'.$authorNameDir;
```

This is a relative path, so presumes the script running is in the parent to your `user-uploads` dir. Otherwise you'll have to set the path as required.